# React: provide default file for upload

Tags: reactjs, file, upload

I am trying to create a react app where the user can upload files and that provides a default file if the user does not select one. However I can't seem to find a way to create a File object from an imported img. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0YPy.png)

App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import defaultImg from "./default_files/logo192.png"

class App extends Component {
  // Set initial state
    state = {
    img: {file: null, // <-- create File object from defaultImg here
          preview: defaultImg,}
    };

    onImgChange = event => {
    //update state on image upload
    this.setState({img: {file:event.target.files[0],
                         preview: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])},
                  });
    };

  function = () => {
    //dostuff
    return
  }
    render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <img src={this.state.img.preview} style={{ width: 192, height: 256 }} alt="noimg"/>
        <input type="file" onChange={this.onImgChange} />
      </div>
    );
    }
}

export default App;
```